Getting error highlighted in yellow in eclipse while automating post API through rest assured
[Getting error highlighted in yellow in eclipse while automating post API through rest assured]
package com.testautomation.apitesting;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

public class PostAPIRequest {
    
    @Test
    
    public void createBooking() {

        JSONObject booking= new JSONObject();
        JSONObject bookingdates= new JSONObject();
           
           booking.put("firstname","Garima");
           booking.put("lastname", "Nandal");
           booking.put("totalprice", "1000");
           booking.put("depositpaid", "true");
           booking.put("additionalneeds", "Breakfast");
           booking.put("bookingdates", "bookingdates");
           
           bookingdates.put("checkin", "2024-06-26");
           bookingdates.put("checkout", "2024-06-27");
           
           RestAssured
           .given()
           
           .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
           .body(booking.toString())
           .baseUri("https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking")
           
           .when()
           .post()
           .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200);
            
           
    }
}

Error message is showing in attached SS.
Can anyone help me please.
I tried passing values for post api using put method and expected that test case should get pass for creation of data. I was expecting 200 or 201 but getting 500 in console. Not sure, what's going wrong.
Error in yellow says:

Type safety: The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type
HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be
parameterized


The warring that Eclipse shows you is not related with what server responds. You may find some context of your warnings issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35453263/8343843
The server responds with 500 because it internally fails while processing your request. I believe that it happens because of that your line:
booking.put("bookingdates", "bookingdates");

Looks like you just put a string where you expect to have some nested object. Thus the server fails to parse it since it is not a json object.
I did not deal with org.json.simple but probably something like this would help:
   ...
   booking.put("additionalneeds", "Breakfast");
   
   bookingdates.put("checkin", "2024-06-26");
   bookingdates.put("checkout", "2024-06-27");

   booking.put("bookingdates", bookingdates);
   ...

